# Function and procedure subprogram

Tags: ada

I need to only use one function and one procedure and unfortunately I didn't manage to solve this problem.

The problem goes as following:

> Create a subprogram that has three parameters. One string and two sign.
>
> The subroutine must pick the first and last character in the string. The main program will then print these two characters.
>
> Create a subprogram that retrieves a character, from the keyboard, which represents a truth value (see driving example).
>
> The subprogram must send back the corresponding truth value to the main program.

In the terminal it should look like:

```
Type a string containing 6 characters: Overfl
First character is: O
Last character is : l

Type F or T (for False or True): T
You typed True
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Test is

   procedure String_Check(
      S : in String;
      Char_1, Char_2 : out Character
   ) is
   begin
      Char_1 := S(S'First);
      Char_2 := S(S'Last);
   end String_Check;
   
   
    function Character_Check return Boolean is  
   Check : Integer; 
  begin


   Put("Type F or T (For False or True): ");
   Get(Check)

      if Check = 'T' then
         return True;
      else
         return False;
      end if;
   end Character_Check;
   
   Char_1, Char_2 : Character;
   Check          : Character;
   S              : String(1 .. 6);
   
begin
   Put("Type a string containing 6 characters: ");
   Get(S);
   String_Check(S, Char_1, Char_2);
   Put("First character is: ");
   Put(Char_1);
   New_Line;
   Put("Last character is: ");
   Put(Char_2);
   Skip_Line;
   New_Line(2);
  
   Put("You typed ");
   
   if Character_Check then
      Put("True");
   else
      Put("False");
   end if; 
end Test;
```

My code runs but it doesn't fulfill the given requirements. I guess I can't use a function in my second subprogram because the instruction says `"create a subprogram that receives a character from the keyboard".` How am I supposed to do `Get` in a `function`? But if I make my second program to a `procedure` I have to make my first program to a `function`. How am I supposed to do `return` for two values at the same time?

Comment: What makes you think you can’t call `Get` in a function? have you tried?

Comment: How am I supposed to Get in a function when the only mode in a function is “in”? In that case what are putting as a “in” parameter?

Comment: Also what am I supposed to the with the text? Should I include it in the function?

Comment: There is no rule that says a function has to take any parameters at all.

Comment: So a function doesn’t have to have any parameters and it can still return a value?

Comment: Why doesn’t it work when I type ‘function Char_Check return Character is …..

Comment: @leun  How about a challenge for Character_Check, can you rewrite it so it just has a return statement?

Comment: 1. A function can have parameters of any mode (changed in Ada 12). 2. A function has a declarative region between `is` and `begin`. what can you do in a declarative region?

Comment: @leun ... yes ... can you think of a way such a function could ... get a value?

Comment: @Jim Lewis I updated my code but it didn’t work and I quite frankly didn’t expect it to work either. I’m using Ada 95 btw

Comment: @user_1818839 Not really but if a function can have an empty parameter list then that way you should be able to Get a value

Comment: @Jeffrey R. Carter you declare variables I guess

Comment: also how can I prevent from typing my text in my function?