# Duplication of code in main program solution

Tags: ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure TF is

   function Character_Check return Boolean is  
      Check : Character; 
   begin
      Get(Check);

      if Check = 'T' then
         return True;
      else
         return False;
      end if;
   end Character_Check;
   
begin
   Put("Type F or T (For False or True): ");

   if Character_Check then
      Put("You typed True");
   else
      Put("You typed False");
   end if; 
end TF;
```

I need to get a character in my actual function and I have a hard time not duplicating my code. You can see a very obvious duplication where it says "You typed " twice. I can fix it by typing the text in my function but that's not allowed so I wonder if theres anyway to fix this?

Comment: You are probably allowed to use a boolean variable in the main program, for another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could exchange this lines into one long:

```
Put("You typed " & (if Character_Check then "True" else "False"));
```

or

```
Put("You typed " & Boolean'Image(Character_Check));
```

Just the second solution will make text capitalized (`TRUE` and `FALSE`).

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @thindil provides a good example of using a conditional expression to achieve the result you want. You can also substantially streamline your `Character_Check` function by simply returning the boolean value already generated.

Rather than:

```
   function Character_Check return Boolean is  
      Check : Character; 
   begin
      Get(Check);

      if Check = 'T' then
         return True;
      else
         return False;
      end if;
   end Character_Check;
```

Simply use:

```
   function Character_Check return Boolean is  
      Check : Character; 
   begin
      Get(Check);

      return Check = 'T';
   end Character_Check;
```

This is what Jim Lewis was [trying to point you to 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217991/function-and-procedure-subprogram#comment124130820_70217991) in comments on a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

For `Character_Check`, what about

```ada
function Character_Check return Boolean is
   Check : Character;
begin
   Get(Check);

   return (case Check is
              when 'F'    => False,
              when 'T'    => True,
              when others =>
                 raise Constraint_Error with "F or T, doofus");
end Character_Check;
```